# Can a camera "tighten on" a subject?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I have encountered cameras "tightening on" something several times in reading. Examples:

> The camera tightened on O'Doyle's face. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=bS5Xkc_87ywC&pg=PA362&lpg=PA362&dq=%22camera%20tightened%20on%22&source=bl&ots=mgwezMVd1n&sig=ACfU3U2JqfSd9bYenfQqxYX75XIj3Rk5jQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj90aHco63hAhVOdt8KHRZADpEQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22camera%20tightened%20on%22&f=false))
>
> The camera tightened on his face. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=LhVSAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=%22camera%20tightened%20on%22&source=bl&ots=mWkl84LrQX&sig=ACfU3U3VOcvN5IPK8mj4SjUCc8o9nPdPxQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj90aHco63hAhVOdt8KHRZADpEQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22camera%20tightened%20on%22&f=false))
>
> The camera tightened on the reporter as she stared into it. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=dw7NBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA359&lpg=PA359&dq=%22camera%20tightened%20on%22&source=bl&ots=QG7AHCrFRN&sig=ACfU3U3MK8BJckj9s9jxMTWfMik5l-lZ6w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj90aHco63hAhVOdt8KHRZADpEQ6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22camera%20tightened%20on%22&f=false))
>
> The camera tightens on another amazing find. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=1uXTDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT233&lpg=PT233&dq=%22camera%20tightens%20on%22&source=bl&ots=gvv5FevnOp&sig=ACfU3U3iho5L7nh8D_ScUOF5s6IS-_A-CQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCxJbZo63hAhUiVt8KHTsmBKwQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22camera%20tightens%20on%22&f=false))

But this usage of "tighten" can't be found in dictionaries. It seems to mean along the lines of "zoom in on". What does it mean exactly? Is this usage idiomatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does mean "zoom in".

One sense of "tight" is narrow or close; think about "tight trousers". It is this sense that is being used to describe "getting the camera close to the subject so it fills the frame".

Comment: **Tighten the shot** and **go in tighter** are typical requests from a TV producer to a camera operator.